# How to not allow generate error element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I work with jquery.validate and I search a way how not allow to validator to generate error element.

```
$("#smsForm").validate({
  highlight: function (element) {
    $(element).addClass("notvalid");
  },
  unhighlight: function (element) {
    $(element).removeClass("notvalid");
  }
});
```

I just want to add not valid class to input field without generate any input elements.
But validator add :

```
<label for="phoneNumber" generated="true" class="error">Phone</label>
```

for example if phone number not correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I *think* that if you set the `errorElement` option passed to `.validator()` to anything other than `"label"`, then the validate plugin will not generate an error element for you. For example:

```
$("#smsForm").validate({
            errorElement: "",
            highlight: function (element) {
                $(element).addClass("notvalid");
            },
            unhighlight: function (element) {
                $(element).removeClass("notvalid");
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The error element in jQuery validate is just a css class, i.e.

```
<input id="email" class="email error" type="text">
```

For example, in above, the class is "email error".

If you don't want the error element to "show up" you can just change the css style in your stylesheet:

```
.error {
  background-color: #fff; /* make the pink/red colour white */
  display: none; /* another way to hide it...*/
}
```

**If** what you are asking is how to "hide" the error message...if you don't want the .error class added, that's something else.

Comment: Yes. But if i add .error class css (display:none) , so validator put style display:inline... :(

Comment: I want to hide error element or not allow to generate... It does not matter